What does "then" signify in the context of "my whole life" already being mentioned?
In Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3 (2023), Mantis speaks to Guardians of the Galaxy:

Mantis: I love you all. I do. But my "whole life" I did whatever Ego wanted,
and then, I did whatever the Guardians wanted.

What does "then" signify in the context of "my whole life" already being mentioned?

Just a note: use italics or bold to emphasize a phrase, not quotation marks.

I agree with ishtar's answer. It's the standard use of then meaning "after that". Adding this answer because it's a good opportunity to show how tenses could have clarified things a little.
The speaker is thinking back to the time when they had been doing only what Ego wanted, which, up to that point, was all that they had ever done. Here's a slightly edited version:

Mantis: I love you all. I do. But my whole life I'd done whatever Ego wanted, and then, I did whatever the Guardians wanted.

